How to turn 0-5 V DC voltage from a DAC chip into an audio voltage range?
I'm messing around with some 16-bit DAC chips and wanted to experiment with audio playback on an MCU. First I'd make some square wave and sawtooth wave tones and later play an audio file from an SD card.
What method can I use to turn the 0-5 V DC voltage into audio range, which is suppose to be AC? Except someone had told me that it isn't appropriate to call it AC, instead to call it DC with an offset.

Remove the offset with a DC-blocking/AC-coupling capacitor.
For all we know, depending on where you will feed in the audio, the input may already remove it for you. But it is a good idea to remove it on your output.

Are there any magazines / reading material where I can take a look at learning this concept?

@user2175010 A simple RC high pass filter will remove the DC offset and rebias the DC to 0V. Basic audio circuit examples should cover this.


someone had told me that it isn't appropriate to call it AC, instead
to call it DC with an offset.

No, it's AC with a DC offset thus making the signal swing centred on a DC level that is half the numerical digital range of the DAC. If you need AC you can feed the AC+DC through a high-pass filter made from a capacitor and resistor.

Does the high pass filter not cut out low frequencies of the sound? Or is that only a factor when passing already DC offset signal though another high pass filter?

You choose a cut-off frequency that is below the lowest frequency that you wish to pass i.e. below 20 Hz for audio @user2175010
